# Getting an array of responses in then using $.when.apply

Tags: jquery, ajax, .when

I have the following code:

```
var requests = [];

var files = ['one.html', 'two.html', 'three.html'];

for(var i = 0; i<files.length; i++){
        requests.push($.get(files[i]));
}

$.when.apply(undefined, requests).
then(function(resultOne, resultTwo, resultThree){
    console.log(resultOne[0]);
})
```

I wish to avoid having to define variable for each response in the .then and instead retrieve an array of responses.

How should I go about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every function scope there is a special array like object in its scope called [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) which corresponds to the values passed to the function call.

You can use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object and iterate over it

```
$.when.apply(undefined, requests).
then(function(resultOne, resultTwo, resultThree) {
  $.each(arguments, function(i, val) {
    console.log(val);//it will be another array with 3 values
    console.log(val[0]);//to get the data returned by the ajax request
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks boss, this was exactly what I was looking for :)